# Reading Users from Azure AD b2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I created Azure AD b2c, created user flows and configured with MVC core application. I am using Local Account as Identity Provider. Authentication and sign up is working fine. Some users are signed up and able to access the application. No my requirement is to show all users in AD in my applications users screens so admin can manage/view instead going to azure portal.

To read the users I provided Users.Read.All permission in API permission under my application, also using Graph API to load the users data. I am able to get users data but not email in it.

Can you please let me know if is there any chance to get the users data along with email.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your user registered by email?

Comment: B2C application registrations do not provide permissions to Graph API. So you need to explain in extreme detail how you have achieved this, and how the B2C user obtains a token to Graph API.

Comment: not sure where you got that from jas suri, i'm looking at a b2c app reg right now and under api permissions there is 2 default graph permissions and if you click add you can choose more graph permissions.

Comment: I referred the below links https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api   
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management

Comment: That is an Azure Ad app registration, you selected (for users in this directory) when creating it. The email of the user is in the signInNames collection for a B2C local account. Federated identities may not be writing the email to the account. If your app is protected by B2C, then the users token will not be able to access graph api. If the app is protected by the same app registration as the one with Graph permissions (AAD app reg) then the users token will be able to access graph api, but that is not a B2C auth.